# How do I use StyleCop with Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, stylecop

I am building my c# code using Roslyn like this:

```
    var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(projectPath).Result;
    var project = solution.GetProject(solution.ProjectIds[0]);
    var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
```

After the compile I can access any warning or errors by doing:

```
    System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Diagnostic> DiagnosticMessages = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
```

This gives me any errors and warning for the project but not any from StyleCop. The .csproj is using StyleCop.

How do I compile using Roslyn and also use StyleCop and have it return warnings and errors from the compilation and from StyleCop?

I have Roselyn installed and I have a solution, project and compilation successfully.  I can see the errors and warnings from the Visual Studio compiler, but I can not see the warnings from StyleCop.

I want to see the StyleCop Error number, and the StyleCop Warning or Error message.

I do have StyleCop turned on on the solution that is in ProjectPath.
It correctly shows the warnings if I build using visual studio on that solution.

I expect to see the same list of errors and warnings that I get with Visual Studio compile on that Solution.

But the actual results are the errors and warnings from the compiler but none are present from the StyleCop. I am using StyleCop 1.1.118.

Comment: What `StyleCop` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By default roslyn will only show you compiler diagnostics. You can ask for analysis to run for a set of analyzers using `compilation.WithAnalyzers` from the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics` namespace. An example of getting *all* diagnostics for a given project would look something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

public static class RoslynExtensions
{
    static async Task<ImmutableArray<Diagnostic>> GetAllDiagnosticsForProjectAsync(this MSBuildWorkspace workspace,
                                                                                   string projectPath,
                                                                                   CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(projectPath, cancellationToken: token);
        var project = solution.GetProject(solution.ProjectIds[0]);
        var analyzers = project.AnalyzerReferences.SelectMany(ar => ar.GetAnalyzers(project.Language)).ToImmutableArray();
        var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync(token);
        var compilationWithAnalyzers = compilation.WithAnalyzers(analyzers, project.AnalyzerOptions);
        var diagnostics = await compilationWithAnalyzers.GetAllDiagnosticsAsync(token);
        return diagnostics;
    }
}
```